# Strange caching issues in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've come across something quite specific and wondering if anyone out there has faced the same issue.

My SQL query (in a Stored Procedure) is simple, I've simplified it a little but:

```
BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT
            [ANU].[OldUserId] AS [ID]
            ,[ANU].[Email]
        FROM
            [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [ANU]
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[User] AS [U]
        ON
            [U].[ID] = [ANU].[OldUserId]
    END
```

Pretty simple, and the SP is fine when run directly through SQL Management Studio.

However, I run it via Entity Framework as such:

```
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 0)] // used this out of desperation
 public List<DriverDTO> GetByOrganisation(int organisationId, bool isManager)
 {
      return _context.Set<DriverDTO>().FromSql("dbo.New_User_List @OrganisationId = {0}, @IsManager = {1}", organisationId, isManager).ToList();
 }
```

DriverDTO:

```
public class DriverDTO
{
      [Key] // tried removing this also
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

It runs and brings back results, fine. However these results are getting cached. Every call to the SP after the first call brings back the same results, even if I update the records. So, say I edit a User record and change the email - the originally fetched email will always be brought back.

Again, running the SP via SQL Manager brings back the correct results, but my C#/EF side does not. The only logical thing in my head here is that something is somehow being cached under the hood that I desperately need to get around?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loaded entities are cached in the `DbContext` (in each `DbSet`'s `Local` collection).

There are several options:

1. Use `AsNoTracking` for your query:

   ```
   return _context.Set<DriverDTO>()
              .AsNoTracking()
              .FromSql("dbo.New_User_List @OrganisationId = {0}, @IsManager = {1}", organisationId, isManager)
              .ToList();
   ```

   This should avoid Entity Framework caching completely for this query
2. Use a new `DbContext` instance for each query
3. Alternatively, detach all cached entities from the context before issuing your query... something like (untested):

   ```
   _context.Set<DriverDTO>().Local.ToList().ForEach(x=>
   {
      _context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;
   });
   ```

   Notice that, opposite to what one may think, you can't use `_context.Set<DriverDTO>().Local.Clear()`, since this will mark your entities as deleted (so if you `SaveChanges` afterwards, it'll delete the entities from the database), so be careful if you are experimenting with the local cache.

Unless you have a need to use a single `DbContext` or have the received entities from the SP attached to it, I'd go for #2. Otherwise, I'd go for #1. I put #3 there for completeness but I'd avoid mangling with the local cache unless strictly necessary.

Comment: You've saved my bacon today in a big way, thank you! The .AsNoTracking() function worked an absolute treat for me and is the simplest route to go down for my scenario. I just hope this helps others too.

Comment: @ChrisDixon glad it helped. As a side note, `AsNoTracking` queries are much faster and require less than half the memory than normal EF querying... so I'd use it always unless there's a reason not to (basically, wherever your context will be used only for querying, and not for updating/deleting)

Comment: Brilliant advice. Learn something new every day and will speed up my system dramatically!